# What is the purpose of the Dream Chaser carry test?

Tags: commercial, testing

I was reading that recently the Dream Chaser completed a carry test. Seems like they hung it from a helicopter and flew around with it.  What benefit would this have over a wind tunnel test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe are called *"captive-carry"* or *"captive-carriage"* tests. Their purpose is to verify integrated spacecraft performance under landing and rollout conditions.

In the case of these captive carry Dream Chaser tests at Nasa's Dryden Flight Research Centre in California, run by NASA partner Sierra Nevada Corporation (SNC) of Louisville, Colorado, an Erickson Air-Crane helicopter picked up a test version of the Dream Chaser and flew it a distance of three miles at a maximum altitude of 12,400 feet.

> The tests ensure the Dream Chaser would operate properly upon landing
>   and that the spacecraft will come to a controlled stop after touching
>   down on the runway. SNC’s Dream Chaser team is now preparing for the
>   next CCP tests including a captive carry test, and an approach and
>   landing free flight test, all of which are scheduled for later this
>   fall.

<sup>Press release: [Sierra Nevada Corporation's Dream Chaser® Completes Ground Tow Tests for Upcoming Approach and Landing Test](http://www.prweb.com/releases/2013/8/prweb11023986.htm)</sup>

[image: Dream Chaser captive carriage test]

<sup>Dream Chaser flight vehicle lifted by an Erickson Air-Crane helicopter during a captive-carry test (Credit: [Sierra Nevada Corp.](http://www.sncorp.com/))</sup>

Among tests performed were systems verifications, including flight computer and flight software, instrumentation, guidance, navigation and control, braking and steering performance, flight control surface actuation, mission control and remote commanding capability, and landing gear dynamics.